# How to start rendering (and save result) in terminal on Ubuntu?

Tags: rendering, command-line, linux

I am getting ready, to try out cloud computing for Blender rendering,
that's why I'm curious if I can just drop the .blend file and render the scene from the terminal.

**PS:** Can Somebody tell me if I can save the result right to my disk without saving it on the virtual computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
blender --background /path/to/FileName.blend -f 1
```

More information on Command Line rendering [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html).

Comment: Are there some docs ? Regarding this topic?

Comment: blender --help
or
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html

Comment: Thanks, for fast help

Comment: No problem, could you tick your answer as answered? @tommy

Comment: Can you up vote my question?